# Drop down list that loads on form (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a major problem here that deals with the drop down list in PHP. Could anyone tell me how to automatically load a drop down list on a form. For example, I have 2 options in my drop down list. These options are fruits and vegetables. Let's say that the default value is fruits, so automatically the photos or list of photos are all fruits and then when I select vegetables in my drop down list, it will automatically changes and turn the photos/list of photos into all vegetables without clicking anything.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can handle this a couple ways. Since you did not mention javascript let's go PHP and the onclick listener in js:

```
<?php
$type = "fruit";
if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
}
?>
<form id="some_form" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="type" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="fruit" <?php echo ($type == 'fruit' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Fruit</option>
            <option value="vegetable" <?php echo ($type == 'vegetable' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Vegetable</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="fruits" <?php echo ($type == 'vegetable' ? 'style="display:none"' : ''); ?>>
    fruit images here
</div>
<div id="vegetables" <?php echo ($type == 'fruit' ? 'style="display:none"' : ''); ?>>
    vegetable images here
</div>
```

Comment: can you make another example? but now use javascript and/or jquery to make it more convenient for the user. Thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript as well. Here is my suggestion.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <div align="center"">
  <select name="optionType" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option>Choose One To Submit This Form</option>
    <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

Once you change that the form will POST. So your can get the $_POST["optionType"] value from PHP and do necessary.

Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

add javascript function to onchange event of select box. in the javascript function, submit the form if you need to do all the changes in php, otherwise use ajax request to retrieve relevant div part with images and replace current div with images. if you are using jquery, this can be done easily.